# Add a trailing slash mod_rewrite

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, mod-rewrite

just wondering how I add a trailing slash at the end of my URL's using Mod_Rewrite?

This is my .htaccess file currently:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?pageName=$1
```

My URL show like so:

wwww.****.com/pageName

I want it to show like so:

wwww.****.com/pageName/

The URL is holding a GET request internally, but I want it to look like a genuine directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to have '*mod_rewrite*' module enabled.

```
# a2enmod rewrite
```

Then make sure your configuration file has

`RewriteEngine on`

before following rules are applied.

Here is rule that will check if REQUESTED

- file does not exists
- request is not for index.php
- REQUESTED_URI does not end with /

then

make external redirect (301) to your domain.tld/ with whatever was requested and / appended. Make this last rule of given set.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Next rule

- if new request, file does not exist
- if directory does not exist
- if request is not for index.php

Then
 pass through all requested as '*pageName*' param to index.php / make this last rule and do query string append.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pageName=$1 [L,QSA]
```